# WebDav Problem svn: PROPFIND of '/dir/dir' 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: svn, apache, webdav

I get the following error when attempting to export my SVN repo files from my development server which is running SVN and WebDAV to my stage server which is running on a hostgator account.

Here is the full error:

```
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/egr/trunk'
svn: PROPFIND of '/svn/egr/trunk': 301 Moved Permanently (http://some.no-ip.info)
```

Here is the SVN command I am using:

```
svn export http://some.no-ip.info/svn/egr/trunk . --force --username myusername
```

My WebDAV virtual host configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName some.no-ip.info
        DocumentRoot /var/svn/

        <Directory /var/svn/>
                Options Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /svn "/var/svn/"
        <Location "/svn">
           DAV On
           DavDepthInfinity on
           SVNParentPath /var/svn/
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "SVN Login"
           AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
           Require valid-user
       </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Before you ask yes I plan on using this for multiple projects that already exist within /var/svn so this is why I have attempted configuring it with SVNParentPath.  A decent amount of stuff comes back in google regarding this error, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: Dumb question but have you tried accessing the repository in your browser? Also you should probably remove that `Alias` directive.

Comment: Yes, the repo shows up as an apache directory listing (says in the footer), oddly I thought it should show up as a web dav svn repo or something like that in the footer.  I can auth through the browser and see my files, but can't remotely export the svn.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I finally resolved the problem.  I moved all of the SVN/WebDAv configurations out of my virtual host config leaving it looking like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myhost.no-ip.info
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerAlias egr.localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/svn/egr/trunk
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        Options Indexes None
</VirtualHost>
```

I then went into /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf and configured it like so:

```
 <Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /var/svn/
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "SVN Repo"
     AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
     <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
     </LimitExcept>
  </Location>
```

I can no access my SVN repo with a remote (as well as local svn client) and also have apache render the files through HTTP.